# VirtualBox states "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)."

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am using VirtualBox v5.2.0r118431 and using an HP EliteBook 840 G3.  When I try to launch a CentOS guest I am receiving the error "VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)."  First thing was to check the BIOS and both VT-x and VT-d are enabled in the BIOS.  I did find another SuperUser article [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1153470/vt-x-is-not-available-but-is-enabled-in-bios), but after disabling the Hyper-V service(s) then rebooted I still see the same area.  The following services are shown as disabled in the Services tab under Computer Management:

```
Hyper-V Data Exchange
Hyper-V Guest Services Interfaces
Hyper-V Guest Shutdown Service
Hyper-V Heartbeat Service
Hyper-V PowerShell Direct Service
Hyper-V Remote Desktop Virtualization Service
Hyper-V Time Sync Service
Hyper-V Volume Shadow Copy Requestor
```

I didn't see any other services related to Hyper-V enabled.  Any thoughts what I can determine is causing the resource conflicts?  Perhaps an anti-virus?

Thanks and regrads

Comment: “Perhaps an anti-virus?” - You tell us.  We know nothing about your system.  Why did you disable Hyper-V instead of uninstalling the feature itself?  Disabling it isn’t enough

Comment: did you install docker or any android VMs?

Comment: This is a work computer which I was handed just a few days ago.  I don't believe there are any docker images on the machine.    I was asking if a anti-virus might cause the issue since I am unsure, hence my question.