# Virtualization does not work anymore

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, cpu, bios, virtualization

I have a CLEVO PC and since I've owned it I've always used VirtualBox to create VMs.

Recently, I noticed that in the BIOS there is no option to disable and enable the VT-X function. So I updated the BIOS to the latest version but unfortunately the option was not added. Actually from the BIOS I can only enable the VD-T function

I took advantage to update Windows from scratch and I reinstalled my virtual machine.

Everything worked without problems, when one day he program gives me the error:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
```

Through the "securable" app I discovered this:
[image: Screenshot]

But I'm sure my processor supports the VT-X function as confirmed by [Intel’s ARK](https://ark.intel.com/en/products/88967/Intel-Core-i7-6700HQ-Processor-6M-Cache-up-%20to-3_50-GHz):

However the Intel app on the machine itself says otherwise:
[image: Screenshot]

Then I saw with CPUID that the bit of the register 0x3A of my processor is set to 1, which means if I remember correctly: activate VMXON in SMX mode.

Anyone have an idea?

FWIW, I'm using Windows 10 and a friend of mine has the same PC as mine but with no updates; I did the various tests and on its pc the CPU register bit is 5 and in fact "securable" in the hardware virtualization voice says yes so it's the BIOS update.

And I alredy turned off hyper-v, not work... In the meantime I have re-enabled the hyper-v function and I use the Windows manager to virtualize

Comment: Perhaps one of the patches for Meltdown or Spectre is blocking virtualization.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Except those patches have literally nothing to do with VT-x

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: How would you know?  Microsoft suddenly turned OS?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Meltdown and Spectre have nothing to do with virtualization.  How I know isn’t relevant.

Comment: Apart from allowing one VM to read the memory of another.

Comment: Perhaps you'll accept someone else's word for it: "Oracle updates include the fix for the Spectre CVE-2017-5715 vulnerability affecting its Oracle X86 Servers and Oracle VM VirtualBox" (https://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/67855/security/oracle-january-2018-critical-patch.html)

Comment: Is [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1153493/327367) relevant to you?

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: a friend of mine has the same PC as mine but no updates; I did the various tests and on its pc the CPU register bit is 5 and in fact "securable" in the hardware virtualization voice says yes so it's the BIOS update

Comment: And I alredy turned off hyper-v, not work... In the meantime I have re-enabled the hyper-v function and I use the Windows manager to virtualize

Comment: If you've enabled Hyper-V, that will cause any apps or Virtualbox to show that virtualization is disabled.  After you enable Hyper-V, your host OS is moved into a VM and hardware virtualization isn't passed through.

Comment: I activated hyper-v precisely because I can not use virtualbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, reinstalling windows solve the issue.