# Error with Oracle VM VirtualBox: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vt-x

I've recently installed Oracle VM VirtualBox on my Windows 10 computer, and I'm trying to make an Android Virtual Machine. The problem is that when I go to start the VM, it displays the following error:

```
VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).

Result Code:   
E_FAIL (0x80004005)  
Component: 
ConsoleWrap  
Interface: 
IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

I've already checked that my CPU is compatible with VT-x, and it's activated in the BIOS (In my case, I activated VT-d because there isn't an option for VT-x, but I've read that they're the same thing. If I'm wrong please correct me).
I also have disabled Hiper-V, but it didnt' work.

Do you have any ideas on what's the cause of this problem?

**Edit:**

I have a Gigabyte GA-H270M-DS3H motherboard with the F7 BIOS Version. I have an Intel I7 7700 (not K) CPU

Regarding  [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1153470/vt-x-is-not-available-but-is-enabled-in-bios), I've tried everything there, except for turning on VT-x on the BIOS, because I don't have the option, and because I thought that VT-d was the same thing. If not, how do I turn on VT-x?

Comment: What CPU do you have? You say it's activated in the BIOS, but you activated Vt-d and not Vt-x because it isn't available. Vt-d is not the same as Vt-x.

Comment: Please list: CPU type and what happens if you try to install any standard OS (Windows, Linux)

Comment: @DrZoo: I have a I7 7700 (Not K) CPU. The datasheet from Intel says that it has VT-x technology. By the way: My motherboard is a Gigabyte GA-H270M-DS3H.

Comment: @AndrewQ: As mentioned in my previous comment I have a I7 7700 CPU. When I tried setting up a virtual machine with Ubuntu, it gave the same error. Also, I've noticed that when I went to select the type of OS in VirtualBox, There are no 64-bit options, and both the iso's for Android and Ubuntu are 64-bit

Comment: @milo8505 - You should update your question instead of supplying vital information required to answer your question in a comment.  **I've read that they're the same thing.** - They are most definitely **NOT** the same thing.  **VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)** is being thrown because VT-x isn't enabled.  Get a motherboard that allows you to enable it.

Comment: Make sure you have Core Isolation, specifically Memory integrity, turned off since you are running Windows 10 Version 1803.  If you cannot enable VT-x due to the firmware your motherboard has, then you will have to replace your motherboard, in order to enable.  The error log, clearly indicates VT-x is not enabled, until you enable VT-x you won't be able to run the VM on the machine in question.

Comment: @Ramhound: How do I enable Core Insolation and/or Memory integrity?

Comment: @milo8505 - Why would you enable something I ask you to make sure was disabled?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry, I meant, How do I disable those features?

Comment: Windows Defender Security Center

Comment: @Ramhound It did in fact work, the VM's now work correctly. The only thing, is that in order for me to disable it, I had to change the followink registry key to 0: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled. Please post this as an answer, so I can set the question to "answered"

Comment: @milo8505 - Sounds like you should answer your own question, since my suggestion was regards to Core Isolation, not Device Guard (which is something entirely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was turning off Core Isolation, specifically Memory integrity.

At first, I couldn't access this configuration, but, by changing the following registry key to 0, I could: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled.

Comment: where do you do that??

Comment: At Windows Defender Security Center